# How to write files to a specific directory?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm trying to let the user select a directory and then write files to that directory.

I have this code that lets a user browse for a directory:

```
var file:flash.filesystem.File = new flash.filesystem.File();
file.browseForDirectory("Select a directory");
file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler);

protected function selectHandler(event:Event):void {
    // these contain the path where I want to save files to
    Object(fileReference).url;
    Object(fileReference).nativePath;
    // how do I create a file in that directory?
}
```

How do I create a file in the directory that the user selects?

Comment: what type of file are you wanting to create?

Comment: HTML or XML file. It is an XML.toXMLString()

Comment: Is this flash web or AIR? I must assume it's AIR because you're using the `File` class. In that case, you can use the [FileStream Class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html) and more specifically the `writeUTFBytes()` function of that class (or `writeUTF()`? I always get the two confused).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your select handler code does not seem to be correct. You should get the reference of the Folder which is an object of the type `File` by doing `event.currentTarget`, and not Object or fileReference.

Next you can create a file using the `FileStream` class. Your `selectHandler` code should look like this:

```
protected function selectHandler(event:Event):void 
{
    var targetDirectory:File = event.currentTarget as File;
    var file:File = targetDirectory.resolvePath("htmlFile.html");
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    stream.writeUTFBytes("Any Text you want to create");
    stream.close();
}
```

Will work in AIR projects.

Hope this answers your question.